# Where can I get best silverlight 4 books?

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

Where can I get best SilverLight 4.0 books that discusses about:

1. How do I send and receive data via bluetooth ?
2. How do I send and receive data via wifi 802.11 a/​​b/g ?
3. How do I send and receive data via GPRS and 3.5G ?
4. How do I read data from the GPS ?
5. How do I send and receive data via email ?
6. How do I send and receive data via sms ?
7. How to create local database pragmatically ?
8. How to create user control ?

Thanks

Erwin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just check Amazon:
http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=silverlight+4&x=0&y=0

The product descriptions should let you know if they've got what you're looking for.

Hope this helps!

EDIT:
I should mention that this is the book I've got:
[http://www.amazon.com/Pro-Silverlight-VB-Matthew-MacDonald/dp/1430235489/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1303398148&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430235489)

and it usually has anything I've needed. It does have a section on data controls, but I don't think it has anything for the bluetooth and GPS.